Why is my code giving wrong answer when using 2d ArrayList and passing when using 2d arrays?
Here is the DP question,
Given a ‘N’ * ’M’ maze with obstacles, count and return the number of unique paths to reach the right-bottom cell from the top-left cell. A cell in the given maze has a value '-1' if it is a blockage or dead-end, else 0. From a given cell, we are allowed to move to cells (i+1, j) and (i, j+1) only. Since the answer can be large, print it modulo 10^9 + 7.
For Example :
Consider the maze below :
0 0 0 
0 -1 0 
0 0 0

There are two ways to reach the bottom left corner:
(1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 3) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 3)
(1, 1) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 1) -> (3, 2) -> (3, 3)

Hence the answer for the above test case is 2.
This is my solution using 2d Arrays.
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int f(int i, int j, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mat,int [][]dp){
        if(i == 0 && j == 0)
            return 1;
        if((i < 0) || j < 0 || (mat.get(i).get(j)) == -1)
            return 0;
        if(dp[i][j] != -1)
            return dp[i][j];

        return dp[i][j] =  f(i-1,j,mat,dp)%1000000007+f(i,j-1,mat,dp)%1000000007;
    }
    
    static int mazeObstacles(int n, int m, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mat) {
        int dp[][] = new int[n][m];
        
        // Initialize the dp array with -1
        for (int row[] : dp)
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
       return f(n-1,m-1,mat,dp)%1000000007;
    }
}

This is my solution using 2d ArrayList:
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static int f(int i, int j, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mat, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dp){
        if(i == 0 && j == 0)
            return 1;
        if((i < 0) || j < 0 || (mat.get(i).get(j)) == -1)
            return 0;
        if(dp.get(i).get(j) != -1)
            return dp.get(i).get(j);

        return dp.get(i).set(j , f(i-1,j,mat,dp)%1000000007+f(i,j-1,mat,dp)%1000000007);
    }

    static int mazeObstacles(int n, int m, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mat) {
        // Write your code here.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> dp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                row.add(-1);  // Add 0 to each column in the row
            }
            dp.add(row);  // Add the row to the 2D ArrayList
        }
        return f(n-1,m-1,mat,dp)%1000000007;
    }
}

I'm trying to initialize a 2d ArrayList with -1 initially and based on that am accumulating my DP array.
Please help me find where I went wrong when using 2d ArrayList.

Please provide the necessary data and proper invocation of the code that demonstrates the problem.

You are returning the wrong item in the ArrayList solution.  Set returns the previous element that was replaced, not the new one.
From the JavaDoc.
Specified by:
    set in interface List<E>
Overrides:
    set in class AbstractList<E>
Parameters:
    index - index of the element to replace
    element - element to be stored at the specified position
Returns:
    the element previously at the specified position

Change your last statement to the following.
dp.get(i).set(j, f(i - 1, j, mat, dp) % 1000000007
                    + f(i, j - 1, mat, dp) % 1000000007);
return dp.get(i).get(j);

When I made the change, both solutions returned the value of 2 using your initial maze data.
